# Racking my head for days on "TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Working through the example in Chapter 8 of "Full Stack JavaScript development with MEAN" by Adam Bretz & Colin Ihrig and the code in the book doesn't seem to be complete (probably on purpose). Ive spent a lot of time debugging googling and searching StackOverflow. The script can execute fine right up until insertEmployee and then bails. I cant figure out how the arguments for the insertEmployee arguments (pd, devops, acct) are ever set. Im stuck in "callback hell"!

Basically I'm **using Node to populate a MongoDb**.

> If I set the insertEmployee function to use pd._id for all the
>   employees its fine, but using devops._id or acct._id always results in
>   the error below

```
*TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
    at insertEmployees (/Users/Bluemagma/Sites/NodeJS Example Application/database/humanresourcesSchema.js:111:17)
    at /Users/Bluemagma/Sites/NodeJS Example Application/database/humanresourcesSchema.js:199:3
    at /Users/Bluemagma/Sites/NodeJS Example Application/database/humanresourcesSchema.js:62:4
    at Function.<anonymous> (/Users/Bluemagma/Sites/NodeJS Example Application/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3352:16)
    at /Users/Bluemagma/Sites/NodeJS Example Application/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:1863:18
    at /Users/Bluemagma/Sites/NodeJS Example Application/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:726:13
    at /Users/Bluemagma/Sites/NodeJS Example Application/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
    at done (/Users/Bluemagma/Sites/NodeJS Example Application/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:246:17)
    at /Users/Bluemagma/Sites/NodeJS Example Application/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
    at /Users/Bluemagma/Sites/NodeJS Example Application/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:723:17
    at /Users/Bluemagma/Sites/NodeJS Example Application/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:167:37
    at model.callbackWrapper (/Users/Bluemagma/Sites/NodeJS Example Application/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:1841:11)
    at next_ (/Users/Bluemagma/Sites/NodeJS Example Application/node_modules/hooks-fixed/hooks.js:89:34)
    at fnWrapper (/Users/Bluemagma/Sites/NodeJS Example Application/node_modules/hooks-fixed/hooks.js:186:18)
    at /Users/Bluemagma/Sites/NodeJS Example Application/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3352:16
    at /Users/Bluemagma/Sites/NodeJS Example Application/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:228:5*
```

**Heres my code for humanresourcesSchema.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var db = mongoose.connection;
var dbUrl = 'mongodb://localhost/humanResources';

var TeamSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

var Team = mongoose.model('Team', TeamSchema);

var EmployeeSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        first: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        last: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },
    team: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Team'
    },
    image: {
        type: String,
        default: 'images/user.png'
    },
    address: {
        lines: {
            type: [String]
        },
        postal: {
            type: String
        }
    }
});

var Employee = mongoose.model('Employee', EmployeeSchema);

db.on('error', function () {
    console.log('there was an error communicating with the damn database');
});

function insertTeams (callback) {
    Team.create([{
        name: 'Product Development'
    }, {
        name: 'Dev Ops'
    }, {
        name: 'Accounting'
    }], function (error, pd, devops, acct) {
        if (error) {
            return callback(error);
        } else {
            console.info('teams sucessfully added sir!');
            callback(null, pd, devops, acct);           
        }
    });
}

function retrieveEmployee (data, callback) {
    Employee.findOne({
        _id: data.employee._id
    }).populate('team').exec(function (error, result) {
        if (error) {
            return callback (error);
        } else {
            console.log('*** Single Employee Result ***');
            console.dir(result);
            callback(null, data);
        }
    });
}

function retrieveEmployees (data, callback) {
    Employee.find({
        'name.first': /J/i
    }, function (error, results) {
        if (error) {
            return callback(error);
        } else {
            console.log('*** Multiple Employees Result ***');
            console.dir(results);
            callback(null, data);
        }
    });
}

function insertEmployees (pd, devops, acct, callback) {
  Employee.create([{
    name: {
      first: 'John',
      last: 'Adams'
    },
    Team: pd._id,
    address: {
      lines: ['2 Lincoln Memorial Cir NW'],
      postal: '20037'
    }
  }, {
    name: {
      first: 'Thomas',
      last: 'Jefferson'
    },
    Team: devops._id,
    address: {
      lines: ['1600 Pennsylvania Avenue', 'White House'],
      postal: '20500'
    }
  }, {
    name: {
      first: 'James',
      last: 'Madison'
    },
    team: acct._id,
    address: {
      lines: ['2 15th St NW', 'PO Box 8675309'],
      postal: '20007'
    }
  }, {
    name: {
      first: 'James',
      last: 'Monroe'
    },
    team: acct._id,
    address: {
      lines: ['1850 West Basin Dr SW', 'Suite 210'],
      postal: '20242'
    }
  }], function (error, johnadams) {
    if (error) {
      return callback(error);
    } else {
      console.info('employees successfully added sir!');
      callback(null, {
        team: pd,
        employee: johnadams
      });
    }
  })
}

function updateEmployee (first, last, data, callback) {
    console.log('*** Changin names ***');
    console.dir(data.employee);

    var employee = data.employee;
    employee.name.first = first;
    employee.name.last = last;

    employee.save(function (error, result) {
        if (error) {
            return callback (error);
        } else {
            console.log('*** Changed name to Andrew Jackson ***');
            console.log(result);
            callback(null, data);
        }
    });
}

function removeTeams () {
    console.info("deleting all previously added teams sir!");
    Team.remove({}, function(error, response) {
        if(error) {
            console.error("tried to delete all teams but " + error);
        }
        console.info("done deleting all teams sir!");
    });
}

function removeEmployees () {
    console.info("deleting all previously added employees sir!");
    Employee.remove({}, function(error, response) {
        if(error) {
            console.error("tried to delete all employees but " + error);
        }
        console.info("done deleting all employees sir!");
    });
}

mongoose.connect(dbUrl, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log('there was a problem connecting to the database sir!' + err);
    }
    console.log('connected to the database sir!');
    removeTeams();
    removeEmployees();
    insertTeams(function (error, pd, devops, acct) {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        insertEmployees(pd, devops, acct, function (err, result){

            retrieveEmployee(result, function(err, result) {

                retrieveEmployees(result, function(err, result) {

                    updateEmployee('Andrew', 'Jackson', result, function(err, result) {
                        if (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                    } else {
                        console.info("database activity complete sir!");
                    }

                    db.close();
                    process.exit();
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

**Thank you for your help Node and Mongo Geniuses!** I look forward to learning more about callbacks

Comment: I should add line 111 is "Team: devops._id," the first time Im using an argument other than pd. If I set them all to Team: pd._id then I have no issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function insertTeams (callback) {
    Team.create([{
        name: 'Product Development'
    }, {
        name: 'Dev Ops'
    }, {
        name: 'Accounting'
    }], function (error, pd, devops, acct) {
        if (error) {
            return callback(error);
        } else {
            console.info('teams sucessfully added sir!');
            callback(null, pd, devops, acct);           
        }
    });
}
```

The callback here looks suspicious to me. You are passing an array as a single argument to Team.create(), therefore the callback will be called as `function(err, results)`, where results is an array containing your inserted documents.

So when you are calling your callback like `callback(null, pd, devops, acct);`, the error will be null, pd will be your results array, devops and acct will be undefined.

You can either pass the teams as individual arguments to Team.create, and then the callback will be called with multiple arguments too, or leave it as is and adjust the callback to process the array.

[Mongoose examples.](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create)

Or here is the "Racking my had for days and I just had to remove two brackets" version (hopefully):

```
function insertTeams (callback) {
    Team.create({
        name: 'Product Development'
    }, {
        name: 'Dev Ops'
    }, {
        name: 'Accounting'
    }, function (error, pd, devops, acct) {
        if (error) {
            return callback(error);
        } else {
            console.info('teams sucessfully added sir!');
            callback(null, pd, devops, acct);           
        }
    });
}
```

A few well placed console.log()'s can help a lot with finding out where you loose your variables.

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely try this out and thanks for posting the link to the mongoose docs!

Comment: I took out the brackets as you suggested and it works! I'm still foggy as to how its working but thanks for helping debug!

Comment: In the docs I linked, there is an example (in the grey box), that shows the difference between "pass individual docs" and "pass an array". I think you'll be able to understand the difference from that. Also might i point out stackoverflow's process of accepting an answer :) http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

I get the feeling you're getting an error in the insertTeams function.

When it calls the callback function (insertEmployees) with the error, the function doesn't attempt to catch or handle the error at all if one arises.  Instead, it calls the callback and only passes along the error itself as an argument.  Since insertEmployees doesn't have any error handling it doesn't check to see if an error has happened before it gets started.  Therefore, when it tries to call the _id property of devops, devops is undefined, since it wasn't defined when the function was called.  Therefore, the JS errors out.

For more information you might want to try logging the error in insertTeams if it arises.

Edit: I assume the problem is still that insertEmployees is being called with callback(error).  You can access the _id field of error, since error exists, so that will at least return undefined.  However, the other arguments are not defined, since they aren't passed into the function, so as soon as you try to access the _id fields of them, you get an error, since you are trying to access a field of an undefined object.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks for helping me out!